# How can I fix my Acer One 10 (Windows 8.1) not starting up at all?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, reboot, tablet

It has been about 10 days since I got my Acer One 10 and it has already started showing problems. When I went to use it this morning, nothing happened. I assumed it had zero battery, so I put it to charge, and the LED light on top became red. When I left it charging for a while, the red light turned blue. But when I disconnected the charger, the light went away. I went to turn it on, but nothing would happen. No sounds, completely black screen. I tried booting it up while it was charging (and had blue light) and it still wouldn't work.

Is there a way I can get the Acer One 10 to reboot again? Since I only had it for 10 days before this, I didn't have any important files on it, so if I have to, even a hard reset is OK. Can hard resetting to factory settings help fix this problem, and if it can, how do I hard reset the laptop without having to use the screen in anyway (because the screen stays completely black and is not starting)?

Comment: Are you able to hear any noises coming from the laptop when you turn it on? This would include startup sounds, fans spinning, etc... Do you have a monitor you could connect it to to see if maybe the display/light died?

Comment: If it's only 10 days old then it is still under warranty (I presume) ...

Comment: Alt + F10 at boot gets the Acer recovery manager, see if it works.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I know that. But it would be better if I could just fix the device myself.

Comment: @Moab It didn't work. Even if it had work, I wouldn't have been able to tell because the screen was still black.

Answer (score -1):

i hold down the volume and power for a bit and mine will turn on.

Comment: Volume?  How does that relate?

Comment: Seems to be a windows tablet thing http://winsupersite.com/mobile-devices/surface-pro-3-when-bad-things-happen-good-tablet a explaination of why this woulds would be nice